# How to apply image mask to get everything but the region of interest?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mask

Hi Currently have some code that pulls the region of interest using a mask. I would like to do the opposite eliminate the ROI and just use the background. This is the current code I have. Can anyone help should be fairly trivial but I don't know openCV that well.

```
    cv::Mat detectLanes::createTrapezoidROIInverse(cv::Mat TargetImg , vector<Vec2f> laneEndPoints)
{
    //    float height = TargetImg.rows;
    //    float width = TargetImg.cols;
    // account for 5% error

    cout<<"laneEP"<<laneEndPoints[0][0]<<endl;
    Point LLBI(laneEndPoints[0][0]*1.05,laneEndPoints[0][1]);
    Point LLTI(laneEndPoints[1][0]*1.05,laneEndPoints[1][1]);
    Point RLBI(laneEndPoints[2][0]*0.95,laneEndPoints[2][1]);
    Point RLTI(laneEndPoints[3][0]*0.95,laneEndPoints[3][1]);


    //create Mask to Pull out ROI
    Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(TargetImg.size(),CV_8UC1);
    vector< vector<Point> >  co_ordinates;
    co_ordinates.push_back(vector<Point>());
    co_ordinates[0].push_back(LLBI);
    co_ordinates[0].push_back(LLTI);
    co_ordinates[0].push_back(RLTI);
    co_ordinates[0].push_back(RLBI);
    drawContours( mask,co_ordinates,0, Scalar(255),CV_FILLED, 8 );
    //    mask(Rect(0.1*width,0.3*height,0.55*width,0.5*height)) = 255;
    TargetImg &= mask;
    return TargetImg;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah no worries simple as using:

TargetImg -= mask;

instead.